# mysql "in" clause quite slow(seems to hang)

Tags: mysql

I'm using mysql and a simple query like this seems to hang forever with cpu 100%.

```
  select login_name, server, recharge 
  from role_info 
  where login_name in (select login_name 
                       from role_info
                       group by login_name 
                       having count(login_name) > 1)
```

the table role_info is small, with only 33535 rows.

below is the output of explain:

| id | select_type        | table     | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |

|  1 | PRIMARY            | role_info | ALL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 33535 | Using where |

|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | role_info | index | NULL          | a    | 302     | NULL |     1 | Using index |

show processlist reports the query keeps Sending data.

Query   | 1135 | Sending data | select login_name, server, recharge from role_info where login_name in (select login_name from ...

I can switch to join instead of "in" and it works fine. but still curious why this simple query should act so abnormally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder how many people stumble over this bug again and again. It's long lasting [MySQL bug#32665](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32665), where MySQL 6 is the target version. It means that MySQL will turn you uncorrelated subquery into correlated (executed per row of outer resultset). Just in case, in [this blog](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/30/how-to-optimize-subqueries-and-joins-in-mysql/) post are some ideas how to workaround the limitation when you can't rewrite the query into using `JOIN`s.

Answer (score 0):

In some versions of MySQL, `in` with a subquery is quite inefficient.  The subquery gets executed for each row being processed.  In other words, the results are not cached.  I think this is fixed in the most recent versions.

You know how to fix it, by using a `join`.  In general, I gravitate to `join`s or `exists` in MySQL instead of using `in` with a subquery.